# vue3-date-time-picker / Set custom date. month and year

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Any idea on how to set custom date, month and year on vue3-date-time-picker?

I want to set the date, month an year to a custom value before the user will change it on his own.

https://vue3datepicker.com/

Answer (score 0):

You mean

Options API

```
<script>
import Datepicker from "vue3-date-time-picker";
import "vue3-date-time-picker/dist/main.css";

export default {
  components: { Datepicker },
  data() {
    return {
      date: new Date("2021-12-31"),
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Composition API

```
<script>
import { ref } from "vue";
import Datepicker from "vue3-date-time-picker";
import "vue3-date-time-picker/dist/main.css";

export default {
  name: "Demo",
  components: {
    Datepicker,
  },
  setup() {
    const date = ref(new Date("2021-12-31"));

    return {
      date,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```